# Mark duplicate data with DUP in SQL server with multiple column comparision

Tags: sql-server

I have one table called DebitCatdTransaction, I want to mark duplicate data as DUPPAST in status column but condition is that

Update Status column to DUPPAST if any records is exist with same TPATransactionId , Channel, EIN and Status is not equal to NULL

If you look at below table, so I need to update status to DUPPAST for row number 2 & 3 because 2 & 3 rows data is exactly same and first row's status is not NULL.

Below is my table structure and data

```
+------------------+---------+--------+--------+
| TPATransactionId | Channel | EIN    | Status |
+------------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 55277801         | H       | 137580 | TBD    |
+------------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 55277801         | H       | 137580 | NULL   |
+------------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 55277801         | H       | 137580 | NULL   |
+------------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 55277801         | V       | 137580 | NULL   |
+------------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Below is same script structure

```
DECLARE @DebitCardTransaction TABLE (TPATransactionId INT,Channel VARCHAR(50),EIN INT,Status VARCHAR(50));

INSERT @DebitCardTransaction VALUES (55277801,'H',137580,'TBD')
INSERT @DebitCardTransaction VALUES (55277801,'H',137580,NULL)
INSERT @DebitCardTransaction VALUES (55277801,'H',137580,NULL)
INSERT @DebitCardTransaction VALUES (55277801,'V',137580,NULL)
```

This is what I did so far

```
UPDATE d1
SET d1.Status = 'DUPPAST'
  From @DebitCardTransaction d1 Inner join @DebitCardTransaction d2
  ON d1.TPATransactionId = d2.TPATransactionId
AND d1.Channel=d2.Channel
  AND d1.EIN=d2.EIN
  AND d1.status is null
```

This is what I am expecting output

```
+------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| TPATransactionId | Channel | EIN    | Status  |
+------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 55277801         | H       | 137580 | TBD     |
+------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 55277801         | H       | 137580 | DUPPAST |
+------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 55277801         | H       | 137580 | DUPPAST |
+------------------+---------+--------+---------+
| 55277801         | V       | 137580 | NULL    |
+------------------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *,
   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TPATransactionId, Channel,EIN 
                          ORDER BY Status DESC)
  FROM @DebitCardTransaction
)
UPDATE cte
SET Status = 'DUPPAST'
WHERE Status IS NULL AND rn > 1;

SELECT *
FROM @DebitCardTransaction;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/YSKM69464)**</kbd>

Note: You should add column like `ID IDENTITY(1,1)` to get stable sort and allow to get first record.

```
rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TPATransactionId, Channel,EIN ORDER BY ID)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/RVIE20609)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

> *isn't it possible to do it without CTE*

Yes:

```
UPDATE s
SET Status = 'DUPPAST'
FROM (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TPATransactionId, Channel,EIN 
                                       ORDER BY ID)
      FROM @DebitCardTransaction) s
WHERE Status IS NULL AND rn > 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](http://rextester.com/EXL20889)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your answer, isn't it possible to do it without CTE?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY TPATransactionId
            ,Channel
            ,EIN ORDER BY TPATransactionId
            ) rn
    FROM @DebitCardTransaction
    )
UPDATE dt
SET [Status] = 'DUPPAST'
FROM @DebitCardTransaction DT
INNER JOIN cte c ON dt.TPATransactionId = c.TPATransactionId
    AND dt.Channel = c.Channel
    AND dt.EIN = c.EIN
WHERE rn > 1

SELECT *
FROM @DebitCardTransaction
```